# php gzcompress generates corrupted .zip file

Tags: php, compression, zip

I have to refactor some old php code to update our wiki to 1.28.
i have an Export Plugin, which saves chosen pages into strings.
this strings where added to a zip file and are compressed by gzcompress.

I can download the file, but when i try to open it, it say's "file is corrupted". If I repair the archive with winrar, I get the expected output file.  How can I solve to get the correct .zipfile in the first place

It may have some thing to do with the old ZipHelper we use, but I actually have no idea what is happening there, because I'm quite new to php:

```
class ZipWriter
{
    function __construct()
    {
    }

    var $datasec            = array ();
    var $ctrl_dir           = array ();
    var $eof_ctrl_dir       = "\x50\x4b\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00";
    var $old_offset         = 0;
    var $filename           = "";
    var $filepointer;
    var $writtenSizeCtrlDir = 0;
    var $writtenSizeData    = 0;
    var $writtenFiles       = 0;
    var $completeBuffer;
    var $stream             = false;

    function addFile($data, $name, $time = 0)
    {
        $name = str_replace('\\', '/', $name);

        $dtime    = dechex($this->unix2DosTime($time));
        $hexdtime = '\x' . $dtime[6] . $dtime[7]
            . '\x' . $dtime[4] . $dtime[5]
            . '\x' . $dtime[2] . $dtime[3]
            . '\x' . $dtime[0] . $dtime[1];
        eval('$hexdtime = "' . $hexdtime . '";');

        $fr = "\x50\x4b\x03\x04";
        $fr .= "\x14\x00";            // ver needed to extract
        $fr .= "\x00\x00";            // gen purpose bit flag
        $fr .= "\x08\x00";            // compression method
        $fr .= $hexdtime;             // last mod time and date

        // "local file header" segment
        $unc_len = strlen($data);
        $crc     = crc32($data);
        $zdata   = gzcompress($data);
        $zdata   = substr(substr($zdata, 0, strlen($zdata) - 4), 2); // fix crc bug

        $c_len = strlen($zdata);
        $fr .= pack('V', $crc);             // crc32
        $fr .= pack('V', $c_len);           // compressed filesize
        $fr .= pack('V', $unc_len);         // uncompressed filesize
        $fr .= pack('v', strlen($name));    // length of filename
        $fr .= pack('v', 0);                // extra field length
        $fr .= $name;

        // "file data" segment
        $fr .= $zdata;

        // "data descriptor" segment (optional but necessary if archive is not
        // served as file)
        $fr .= pack('V', $crc);                 // crc32
        $fr .= pack('V', $c_len);               // compressed filesize
        $fr .= pack('V', $unc_len);             // uncompressed filesize

        if ($this->stream) {
            array_push($this->completeBuffer, $fr);
        } else {
            // write the compressed data to the zipfile
            fputs($this->filepointer, $fr);
        }

        // count up the already written data size
        $this->writtenSizeData = $this->writtenSizeData + strlen($fr);

        //$new_offset        = strlen(implode('', $this->datasec));
        $new_offset = $this->writtenSizeData;

        // now add to central directory record
        $cdrec = "\x50\x4b\x01\x02";
        $cdrec .= "\x00\x00";                // version made by
        $cdrec .= "\x14\x00";                // version needed to extract
        $cdrec .= "\x00\x00";                // gen purpose bit flag
        $cdrec .= "\x08\x00";                // compression method
        $cdrec .= $hexdtime;                 // last mod time & date
        $cdrec .= pack('V', $crc);           // crc32
        $cdrec .= pack('V', $c_len);         // compressed filesize
        $cdrec .= pack('V', $unc_len);       // uncompressed filesize
        $cdrec .= pack('v', strlen($name)); // length of filename
        $cdrec .= pack('v', 0);             // extra field length
        $cdrec .= pack('v', 0);             // file comment length
        $cdrec .= pack('v', 0);             // disk number start
        $cdrec .= pack('v', 0);             // internal file attributes
        $cdrec .= pack('V', 32);            // external file attributes - 'archive' bit set

        $cdrec .= pack('V', $this->old_offset); // relative offset of local header
        $this->old_offset = $new_offset;

        $cdrec .= $name;

        // save to central directory
        $this->ctrl_dir[] = $cdrec;
        // count up written files
        $this->writtenFiles++;
    } // end of the 'addFile()' method

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing different file formats. PHP's `gzcompress` produces the zlib format, whereas you are trying to interpret it as a file in the .zip format, which it is not.

As an aside, the names of these functions in PHP are terrible and misleading, since someone might think that `gzcompress` would produce the gzip format. (Which by the way is also *not* the zip format.) But no, `gzcompress` produces the zlib format. If you want the gzip format, you need to use `gzencode`. If you want the raw deflate format, then you need to use `gzdeflate`. So three functions start with `gz`, but only one produces the gzip format.

None of those produce the zip format. For that, as noted by symcbean, you would use the [ZipArchive class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php).

Comment: In the interests of completeness....PHP does support ZIP files with the ZIP extension: http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php